# JMeter : How to handle Control characters in Jmeter TCP sample request

Tags: tcp, jmeter

How to handle Control characters in JMeter TCP sample request. I want to config my TCP string in JMeter TCP sampler request with Control characters. Please refer the attached image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert these control characters from their [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) equivalents using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

1. Declare all the control characters your TCP sampler is using via [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)
2. In your TCP Sampler use something like `${__groovy(URLDecoder.decode(vars.get('variable_name_from_UDV')\, 'ASCII'),)}`

More information: [How to Send Control Characters Using the JMeter TCP Sampler?](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733759-How-to-Send-Control-Characters-Using-the-JMeter-TCP-Sampler--How-to-Send-Control-Characters-Using-the-JMeter-TCP-Sampler?)